# Plotting data with matplot and python to graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to plot 7 days with varying small to large numbers.

The first set of data may look like this

```
dates = ['2018-09-20', '2018-09-21', '2018-09-22', '2018-09-23', '2018-09-24', '2018-09-25', '2018-09-26', '2018-09-27'] 
values = [107.660514, 107.550403, 107.435041, 107.435003, 107.574965, 107.449961, 107.650052, 107.649974]
```

[image: looksright]

vs another set of data may have the same dates, but the values may be much small incremental changes

```
dates = ['2018-09-20', '2018-09-21', '2018-09-22', '2018-09-23', '2018-09-24', '2018-09-25', '2018-09-26', '2018-09-27'] 
values = [0.849215, 0.849655, 0.849655, 0.851095, 0.850885, 0.850135, 0.851203, 0.851865]
```

When I use this

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot_date(x=dates, y=values, fmt="r--")
plt.ylabel(c)
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('static/%s.png' % c)
```

The resulting image for the 1st set of values comes out as a dashed lined connecting the days to the dots. But the 2nd set of data makes a image of 7 parallel lines stacked on top of each other.
[image]

Should I be plotting this differently?

Comment: Use `fmt="r-"` instead of `fmt="r--"`

Comment: One solution is make 2 subplots and share the x axis, [see](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)

Comment: Another one is to broke the y axis, [see](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)

Comment: @SandeepKadapa even with 'r-' it still outputs the same.

Comment: @Lucas they can each be run independently so the data sets should not interfere with each others axis

Comment: It looks like you forgot to clear the previously shown data series on the figure, there should be no reason your code should plot the second series different from the first one and the line above the 100 suggests this is data serie 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would like a comparison between two set of data you provided.

However, with such gap between both sets of data, it could be fairly unclear if you want to show both sets in a same plot.

You could use `plt.subplots()` to do that, and you'll probably get a plot like this
[image: 2 sets in one plot]

Or a better way is just showing two plots separately.. And you'll get a much clearer plot.

[image: data of ALL]
[image: data of EUR]

If you want to just show two plots, you can do something like this.
[image: showing two plots in one output]

Comment: I'm trying to show 2 plots separately, but for some reason it merges them into one? Do I have to do a plt.close() during the for loop?

Comment: This helped, I was missing the plt.close()

Comment: I think you should either create a new figure every time or use `plt.clf()` to clear the figure.

Comment: @nadermx before using `plt.close()`, you can add `plt.show()` so that it will also show the first plot without covering the second plot.

Comment: @Daveedo `plt.show()` is a blocking method, it's not such a good idea to use it in a for loop...

Comment: @toti08 True. I forgot that he's using a for loop... My bad.

Comment: @nadermx I got a chunk of code to show you the rough idea, in which I was not using the for loop. As @toti08 said, `plot.show()` is a blocking method and it's not a good idea to use it in a for loop.